# Qemu 5.2 - nothing shows up after VNC running

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, ubuntu-20.04

i'm trying to use QEMU 5.x for research.

I got QEMU 5.2 source code from qemu.org and installed following instructions.

However, when i tried to run VM by this command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-monitor stdio \
--enable-kvm \
-m 4096 \
-cdrom ubuntu-20.04.iso \
-drive file=img.qcow,if=virtio \
-boot c
-rtc base=localtime \
-device virtio-keyboard-pci \
-vga virtio \
```

then the following texts are printed:

```
QEMU 5.2.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5900
```

then nothing shows up, while QEMU 4.x (used before) pops up a window showing guest ubuntu's GUI.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04. Hope anyone has breakthrough for this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message says that this QEMU is using the VNC protocol for graphics output. You can connect a VNC client to the 127.0.0.1:5900 port that it tells you about to see the graphics output.

If what you wanted was a native X11 window (GTK), then the problem is probably that you didn't have the necessary libraries installed to build the GTK support. QEMU's configure script's default behaviour is "build all the optional features that this host has the libraries installed for, and omit the features where the libraries aren't present". So if you don't have any of the GTK/SDL etc libraries when you build QEMU, the only thing you will get in the resulting QEMU binary is the lowest-common-denominator VNC support. If you want configure to report an error for a missing feature then you need to pass it the appropriate --enable-whatever option to force the feature to be enabled (in this case, --enable-gtk).

If you're running on Ubuntu and your apt sources.list file has deb-src lines in it, the easiest way to install all the dependencies that would get you the same feature list as the real Ubuntu QEMU package is to run "apt build-dep qemu". I recommend that you do that and then re-build QEMU, passing --enable-gtk to configure so you can confirm that the necessary dependencies were installed.

Comment: Yeah, I additionally installed packages in (https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Linux), and it works well. Thanks for help!